# C# Windows Form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Здравствуйте.

У меня есть форма в ней есть элементы textBox , richTextBox и кнопка. После ввода текста в textBox и нажатии на кнопку он форматируется и появляется в richTextBox. После того как я добавляю окало 10 записей появляется ползунок (т.к. размер элемента не позволяет вместить в себя их) и текст идет вниз. Чтобы его увидеть нужно каждый раз проматывать ползунок вниз. Это не совсем удобно. Как сделать так чтобы он проматывался автоматически вниз после добавления записи?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
mySuperRichTextBox.SelectionStart = mySuperRichTextBox.TextLength; // Курсор в конец текста
mySuperRichTextBox.ScrollToCaret(); // И прокручиваемся к курсору
```